# I want to display a different screen when viewed from my phone

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I want to separate the screen when viewed from a phone and when viewed from a PC.
I use react, Typescript, and next.js as my development languages.

I want to display user.tsx when the /user url is accessed from a PC, and Accessdenied.tsx when it is accessed from a smartphone.
How can I separate the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check user come from mobile or web something like this. then redirect

```
const isMobileDevice = /Mobi/i.test(window.navigator.userAgent)
if (isMobileDevice) {
   <Accessdenied />
} else {
   <User/>
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Is there a way to support SSR?

Comment: you can test with this package https://github.com/tokuda109/next-useragent